# Why are MFCCs of different signals equal?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, audio, mfcc

- What I am trying to do:

I am trying to extract features based on the difference between a reference signal (white noise in my case, let's call it ref) and different processed versions of it (let's call one proc_k).

Although the difference signals are not the equal, the MFCCs extracted from these differences are equal like all the `MFCC(ref - proc_k)` are equal.

When I extract the MFCCs from the actual signals and make a difference between the `MFCC_ref - MFCC_proc_k`, the result is a null vector. Why is that? For reference, I extracted 26 MFCCs.

- Initial setup:

The original white noise is in 44.1k, but the processed signals have all been resampled to 22.05k.

- What I tried did so far:

I resampled the original signal and loaded it, but the MFCCs were the same. Then I tried saving the resampled version to the disk as a reference - same issue

Below are the spectra for the reference and one processed signals. They all seem to yield the same MFCCs. Why?

[image: White noise ref resampled to 22.05k]

[image: Processed white noise resampled to 22.05k]

[image]

Comment: Depends on your processing. MFCC only looks at the power spectrum, not the phase. A unit impulse, a linear chirp and white noise will have the same MFCC. If you filter anything with an allpass filter, the power spectrum doesn't change at all. What's your processing like ?

Comment: @Hilmar My processing is with an EQ and peak, shelf and low cut filters as seen in the images. 
The first image is the spectrum of the white noise and the next 2 are the filtered versions.